# How to compare one field with combined fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection like this

```
    sample document
    {
        "field1":"one",
        "field2":"two",
        "field3":"three",
        ...some more key values
    }
```

Now i have field value which is combination of field1, field2 and field3 values. i.e. for above document i have **field = "onetwothree"**
One option is to seggregate that field to 3 different fields but it is not possible because its pattern is not fixed
so I want to compare like this
 `db.collection.find({"filed1+field2+field3":field})`
but it is not possible so one solution is to find all documents from collection and compare one by one but it is not optimized way to do this. So is it any better solution to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with MongoDB v3.6 you can run this query:

```
db.collection.find({
    $expr: {
        $eq: [
            "onetwothree",
            { $concat: [ "$field1", "$field2", "$field3" ] }
        ]
    }
})
```

Here's the documentation on [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) and [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html).